# Setting extent with python in QGIS in new project

Tags: qgis, python, layers, extents

Situation:
I am trying to write a simple python script for QGIS. The script aims to load one layer, zoom to given coordinates, and 'place a pin' there. The coordinates will change every time I run the script, so I cannot create the pin in advance (QGIS is launching from another application which will feed it the coordinates).

My solution to place the pin was to create a second layer with a single point, by reading in a CSV file containing the following:

Latitude,Longitude

-38.6195,142.998

Problem:
My script works to an extent, however if I run it into a blank project it loads the layers but sets the extent to the layer extent of the largest layer, rather than the zoom extent. If I run the script again, it zooms to the correct extent but now has loaded two copies of both layers.

I do not want to install any plugins because I am making a stand alone program which is to open QGIS on other computers. There is no flexibility in that regard. I am new to python, and am curious about why the set extent seems not to work in this particular case. Running the entire script through the python input produces the desired result on the blank canvas.

Here is my script

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

layer = iface.addVectorLayer("C:\paththatworks\meter.shp","meter","ogr")


uri = "file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/pin.csv?crs=epsg:4283&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",", "Longitude", "Latitude")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "pin", "delimitedtext")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)


canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.refresh()

offset = 0.001
pos = [-38.6195,142.998]
zoomRectangle = QgsRectangle(pos[1]-offset, pos[0]-offset,pos[1]+offset,pos[0]+offset)
canvas.setExtent(zoomRectangle)
canvas.refresh()
```

Comment: I tried your and it seems to work (I used a simple line around `pos` saved as `meter.shp`). Maybe I have problems to understand what you actually want to do: calling Qgis on some computer on your network from some program on your computer, switch to remote Qgis (or someone sitting in front of this remote computer) to run the script, which loads both layers and zooms to fixed `pos`? What is the "extent of the largest layer"? The pin layer has an infinite small extent, since it contains only one point. Which CRS is shown in the lower right panel, EPSG:4283 (SRP)?

Comment: Hi Detlev. The problem is the zoom. The layer "meter.shp" covers two or three degrees of latitude and longitude, and I want the window to open to (-38.6,142.9) +\- 0.001 degrees. If there is ANY layer loaded in the window already, that's what happens. But if I run the script on the blank canvas, it zooms to the entire extent of "meter.shp", after loading the layers successfully. If I then run the script again without changing anything, it loads a second version of "meter.shp", and then zooms to the CORRECT extent. I hope that's clear!

Comment: As for the other computers, I mean only that the script needs to work without plugins.

Comment: yep it's EPSG:4283